# Drupal Indexing won't finish

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

Thank you in advance.
I have a site running Drupal 7.35

When I go to the search settings (/admin/config/search/settings), the site is 54% indexed. There are 2232 items left to index. Running a cron will not index any of the remaining 2232 items. What would cause the site to get stuck on the index?
[image]

What could possibly be the issue? I have attempted several fixes with no luck.
Please let me know if you need more information

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem recently. Turns out I had a node with php code in an indexable field that caused the indexing to fail. Maybe that's your problem. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Check the drupal log messages, recently an error prohibited my cron to complete succesfully.